# Jquery 'loading' message while PHP runs MySQLi Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am in the middle of writing a page that does some reporting on a database.
For simplicities sake everything I am including only uses one field. Once I get the concept of what I have to do I can the apply it to the full version, which is a much larger database.

Here is an idea of my structure and what I would like it to be able to do. I have results.php which has a form where the user enters a name and clicks submit. 
when they click submit, I would like it to do a popup (trying BlockUI but open to suggestions) with a 'please wait' message. while in the background getstuff.php is grabbing the name entered and checking the database for that name. once it has found it (or not found it) the blockUI message disappears and under the form in results.php a table is now displayed with the results from getstuff.php

codes:
results.php:

```
<form action="getstuff.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="aplas" name="aplas" class="cmxform">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" id="reportTable">
      <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Name: </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="3" size="10" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="9" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find" id="find"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <div id="content"> </div>
```

getstuff.php:

```
require_once('includes/DbDetails.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "DATABASE")
    Or die("<p><b>Unable to select the database.</b></p>" . "<p>Error Code ".mysqli_errno($DBConnect).": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect))."</p>";
$SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".$name."'";    
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLquery) 
    Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>"."<p>Error Code ".mysqli_errno($DBConnect).": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect))."</p>"; 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);
$tableString = "<table><tr><th>Name:</th></tr><tr><td>{$row[0]}</td></tr></table>";
mysqli_close($DBConnect);
echo $tableString;
```

Javascript in head of results.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#find').click(function(){
        $.blockUI;
        $.post("getstuff.php", $("#aplas").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $.unblockUI;
        });
    });
});
```

it is the blockUI and extra file (getstuff.php) part that I have not done before. originally the results.php form action was to itself and was all contained in one file but while the query was running the page appeared to be doing nothing which is not very user friendly.

I am trying to work out what I need to do in order display `$tableString` from getstuff.php in `<div id="content">` of results.php once the query has finished.

any help with where I am going wrong and how it should look is greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after narrowing the issue down to the jquery I started reading the various APIs regarding forms, .post etc and played around with a few things and then BAM! it started working.

changed the jquery in the head of results.php to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aplas").submit(function(event) {
        $.blockUI();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("getstuff.php", $("#aplas").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $.unblockUI();
        });
    });
});
```

the major change being going from

```
$('#find').click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#aplas").submit(function(event) {
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to echo out the tableString, that's the only thing that's missing in getstuff.php

If you want to send the whole form $.post("getstuff.php", $("#aplas").serialize(), function(data) {});

Comment: I updated the original post to reflect the changes you suggested. it all seems to work eg no errors or anything are displayed and BlockUI pops up then fades away fine as though it is working but there is nothing added to the #content div?

Answer (score 0):

Since you getting the .html(),Check if this will work you

```
require_once('includes/DbDetails.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
@mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "DATABASE")
    Or die("<p><b>Unable to select the database.</b></p>" . "<p>Error Code ".mysqli_errno($DBConnect).": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect))."</p>";
$SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".$name."'";    
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLquery) 
    Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>"."<p>Error Code ".mysqli_errno($DBConnect).": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect))."</p>"; 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);?>
<table><tr><th>Name:</th></tr><tr><td>{<?php echo $row[0]?>}</td></tr></table>
<?php 
mysqli_close($DBConnect);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: I tried the above but get the same result. BlockUI pops up then fades away fine as though it is working but there is nothing added to the #content div. I tried putting an `alert(data);` where `$('#content').html(data);` was as well as after the `$.unblockUI;` but no popup ever gets displayed..

Comment: I changed getstuff.php to have `$name = "jake";` and browsed to getstuff.php and it displays the table on the page with name: jake. so that means it has to be something either in the form post or in the jquery...